# Windows 7: Keyboard shortcut for Safely Remove Hardware dialog

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, safely-remove-hardware

A popular keyboard shortcut to invoke the **Safely Remove Hardware** dialog is to use the destination as:

```
Rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL HotPlug.dll
```

The dialog that is displayed when this shortcut is invoked worked fine in Windows XP. In Windows 7 (64-bit) however, I notice that the same old dialog comes up, but if I choose to **Stop** any plugged device, I get an error. For more on this problem see my [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/216218).

Is there any keyboard shortcut for Windows 7 that actually works with which I can remove devices?

Comment: I have never found one so far, Windows 7 x64 no longer uses hotplug.dll to eject media, I did a process monitor of the normal eject process and W7 uses DeviceDisplayObjectProvider.exe and svchost.exe to bring up the remove safely dialog.

Comment: Moab: Thanks for the investigation! Any idea how to replicate what W7 does using a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Not yet, sorry.